# HP-UX redirect all mails to a single mail id

Tags: sendmail, hp-ux

I want to redirect all mails which are being send from my system to a single mail id.

For example, if I use following command from my system

`echo "This is going to be body of the mail - server" |mailx -r noreply@server.com -s "FOR TESTING - " "santanu@server.com"`

Then above mail should reach to "santanu@another_server.com" mail id (which is already configured in my mail server) INSTEAD of "santanu@server.com" and "santanu@server.com" mail id is fix for all mails, sending from my HP-UX mail server.

I am using HP-UX system (B.11.23) with sendmail (8.11.1) configured.

Comment: A catch-all entry of `@server.com    santanu@anotherserver.com` in the `virtusertable` would likely suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can define SMART_HOST to redirect **all outgoing emails** to single email address.  You can define MAIL_HUB to redirect email addressed to local email addresses.

sendmail.mc

```
dnl send via SMTP to santanu@another_server.com
define(`SMART_HOST',`smtp:santanu@another_server.com')dnl
define(`MAIL_HUB',`smtp:santanu@another_server.com')dnl
```

To redirect to local mailbox use `local:santanu`

**WARNING** It works with modern sendmail version. I am not sure which version of sendmail started supporting smtp:x@y.  You use quite old sendmail version.

**NO sendmail.mc** : If you want to use **discouraged** direct editing of sendmail.cf then modify `DS` and `DH` lines.

```
DSsmtp:santanu@another_server.com
DHsmtp:santanu@another_server.com
```

Comment: Sorry Andrzej, it didn't help.